# Ubuntu 18.04 Files Search: How to Search All?

Tags: unity, 18.04

In 16.04, when typing a search into the search bar in the "Files" window, I was able to search all my files by selecting a button to the right:

Here is what the old "File Search" looked like:

[image]

Now, in 18.04, if I'm in a particular folder and try to search, it only looks in that folder:

[image]

In order to search all my files, I have to navigate to "Home", then *re-type* my search in order to see the files I want:

[image]

The drop-down no longer has the option to search all:

[image]

How do I get back my "Search all files" functionality?

Comment: Two months later, did you find a work around?

Comment: @armipunk Unfortunately, no...I haven't put in a lot of time to try to fix it, either. Still interested in a solution, though.